# List of an object type that prevents backcodes ( like... tbControl.Text = "value" ) from working in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been working with these properties for a while and have never had this problem before. I have a property like this:

```
public List<AirlineTickets_DOL> lstAirlineTickets
{
    get
    {
        if (!(ViewState["lstAirlineTickets"] is List<AirlineTickets_DOL>))
        {
            ViewState["lstAirlineTickets"] = new List<AirlineTickets_DOL>();
        }

        return (List<AirlineTickets_DOL>)ViewState["lstAirlineTickets"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["lstAirlineTickets"] = (List<AirlineTickets_DOL>)value;
    }
}
```

When the data is returned somehow inside the **OnTextChanged** event I have to fill it in as shown below :

```
protected void tbFlightNumber_Book_Ticket_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoFillAirlineTicket(sender);
}

private void AutoFillAirlineTicket(object sender)
{
    TextBox tbFlightNumber_Book_Ticket = ((Control)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("tbFlightNumber_Book_Ticket") as TextBox;
    TextBox tbFrom_Book_Ticket = ((Control)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("tbFrom_Book_Ticket") as TextBox;
    TextBox tbTo_Book_Ticket = ((Control)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("tbTo_Book_Ticket") as TextBox;

    FillFlightData(tbFlightNumber_Book_Ticket, tbDate_Book_Ticket, tbFrom_Book_Ticket, tbTo_Book_Ticket);

    UpdatePanel upAirlineTicket = ((Control)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("upAirlineTicket") as UpdatePanel;
    upAirlineTicket.Update();

    //List<AirlineTickets_DOL> lstAirlineTickets = new List<AirlineTickets_DOL>();

    lstAirlineTickets.Add(new AirlineTickets_DOL
    {
        counter = (nCounter > 0 ? nCounter : 1),
        FlightNumber = tbFlightNumber_Book_Ticket.Text,
        From = tbFrom_Book_Ticket.Text,
        To = tbTo_Book_Ticket.Text,
    });
    nCounter++;
    ListView lstviewAirlineTickets = ((Control)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("lstviewAirlineTickets") as ListView;
    lstviewAirlineTickets.DataSource = lstAirlineTickets;
    lstviewAirlineTickets.DataBind();
}
```

When I remove the comment, the `FillFlightData` function fills the controls (TextBoxes), but when using the property as I explained above, the process of filling the fields does not work and does not give any output on the browser.

> If you need more explain just tell me. I will be happy if someone help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I changed the event to normal onClick Event and make sure the class had to be defined as [Serializable].